# How to formally calculate the Expected Value of this RV

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose that I have a RV $Z$ that with probability $p$ can be a RV $X$ say $N(\mu,\sigma)$ and with probability $1-p$ can be a RV $Y$ say $\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$.

Intuitively I think that $E(Z) = pE(X) + (1-p)E(Y)$

but I don't know how to formally show it.
Something tells me that it has to do with conditional expectation 
Could anyone give me some hint on this?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the law of total expectation, which says that
$$
\operatorname{E} (X) = \sum_i{\operatorname{E}(X \mid A_i) \operatorname{P}(A_i)},
$$
where $\{A_i\}_i$ is a finite or countable partition of the sample space (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) for more details).

Suppose that $W$ is a random variable such that $P(W=1)=p$ and $P(W=0)=1-p$. Then $Z=WX+(1-W)Y$ has the distribution that you describe, i.e. $Z$ is equal to $X$ with probability $p$ and to $Y$ with probability $1-p$. Using the law of total expectation,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname EZ&=\operatorname E(Z\mid W=1)P(W=1)+\operatorname E(Z\mid W=0)P(W=0)\\&=p\operatorname EX+(1-p)\operatorname EY.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for the answer ... could you suggest how to adapt this to my question?

Comment: @HardCore the answer you intuitively obtained is an example of applying the law they mention. What else is there to adapt?

Comment: @HardCore I updated my answer.

Comment: Dear Cm7F7Bb that's exactly what I meant .. thanks for your answer ... it is clear to me now!!!!